# Does rolling a 1 with Advantage cancel out the higher roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, advantage-and-disadvantage

Probably a simple question with a simple answer:

When a player has Advantage -  rolls twice and one is a 1, does this critical fail overrule the advantage roll?

Comment: Note that, if a 1 on either die were a crit fail, then that would mean that Advantage makes you _more_ likely to crit fail than not having Advantage, since there would be two chances to roll a 1 rather than only one chance.

Answer (score 50):

No, a Crit Fail doesn't automatically overrule Advantage.

The *Advantage and Disadvantage* section of the PHB clearly states:

> Use the higher of the two rolls if you have advantage... (pg.173)

Nothing in there says anything that would suggest rolling a 1 would cancel out Advantage so you would still take the higher of the two rolls.

The *Rolling 1 or 20* section states:

> If the d20 roll for an attack is a 1... (PHB pg.194)

So another way to look at it is that the higher of the two rolls becomes the "new" *d20 roll for the attack* and, so long as you haven't rolled two 1s, doesn't meet the requirements for a Critical Fail.

This is also [backed by Mike Mearls (one of the lead designers, though not rules arbiter like Jeremy Crawford, for DnD) on SageAdvice:](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/11/03/20-advantage-critical/)

> **Jerry Hunter**
>   @huntinglabrats
>   @mikemearls A player had advantage on an attack and rolled the first die a 15 and the second a 20, does he get a crit on the attack?
>
> **Mike Mearls**
>   @huntinglabrats Yes - the player uses the better of the two results